# Автоматический выбор языковой версии сайта на PHP - WordPress

Tags: php, wordpress

Нужно при входе пользователя на сайт определять языковую версию сайта по его браузеру. Все это надо реализовать на CMS WordPress. 
Нашел такой код, но понятия не имею как и куда его вставлять.

```
// действие с проверкой языка и установкой куки языка проводим только на странице index.php
if (strpos($_SERVER["REQUEST_URI"], "/index.php") or (substr($_SERVER["REQUEST_URI"], -1)  == "/")) {

// если вход произведен без указания языка
if (!$_GET['lang']) {

    // то проверяем, может язык указан в куках, если нет, то то смотрим локализацию браузера
    if (!$_COOKIE['lang']) {

        $b_lang = explode(",", $_SERVER["HTTP_ACCEPT_LANGUAGE"]);

        // если локализация русская или украинская или белорусская, то считаем, что пользователю необходимо отдавать русскую версию сайта.
        if (($b_lang[0] == "ru") or ($b_lang[0] == "be") or ($b_lang[0] == "ru-UA")) $lang = "rus";

        // при всех остальных локализациях отдаем английскую версию
        else $lang = "eng";

    }

    // если язык уже указан в куках, то его и используем в системе
    else $lang = $_COOKIE['lang'];
}

// если страница запрошена с указанием языка, то этот язык и используем в системе, и запоминаем его в куку
else {
    $lang = $_GET['lang'];
    setcookie("lang", $lang, time()+30758400, "/");
}

}
```

Answer (score 1):

Из комментария очевидно, что нужно этот код вставлять в `index.php`.

Comment: Дело в том что пускай даже этот код выполняет функцию определения языка пользователя, но нет иструкции по эксполутации, что бы зайдя на сайт человек видел подходящую языковую версию сайта.

Comment: Вы вставить его попытались хотя бы? Он работает?